# Selenium - View results from form submission

Tags: python, asp.net, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to fill out a form using Selenium and view the results. After the results are returned, I'll perform additional actions.

I am able to fill in my search terms into the field I want to, but when I try to click the "filter" button on the page, nothing happens.

Based on what I've read, it looks like I have to pass the `__VIEWSTATE` parameter into the next page request, but I can't figure out how to pass this parameter using Selenium.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://mywebsite.com/FilterForm.aspx")

# Enter search term
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="SearchTerm"]')
elem.send_keys("Sample Search")

# Extract __VIEWSTATE value
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__VIEWSTATE"]')
viewstate = elem.get_attribute("value"))

# Filter Results
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="FilterResults"]')
elem.submit()
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your HTML, please? Is the page reloaded when you click the filter button, or is there a background call to an API, and dynamic state change?

Comment: Use javascript and rewrite the submit button with the __VIEWSTATE value?  Then click on sumbit?

Comment: @Sagar The page doesn't really "reload" when I click the filter button--the filtered values appear at the bottom of the page. This is an internal company website, so I can't post a ton of information. What HTML parts do you need?

Comment: @IamBatman How would you pass the __VIEWSTATE value into the submit button?

Comment: Does the __VIEWSTATE need to be quoted? I've used Selenium with dynamic content, but never had to use that. I had added a sleep, and then tested for results from my form submission. That was with JS async calls, though.